# Raspberry Pi + Mcp2515

Tags: python-3, tkinter, can-bus

I used Raspberry Pi + Mcp2515 with CAN bus.

In my code, When I lost request it will locked,then GUI will not working.

```
msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x000601, data=point, extended_id=false)
bus.send(msg)         #Request
bus.flush_tx_buffer()
x = str(bus.recv())   #Ack
print(x)
```

it will locked in x = str(bus.recv()).

when i lost Ack then program will lock in waitting Ack.

but i want to do like When lost Ack it will return to send a new request.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: From the link, what is the summary you have done?

Comment: I mem when i lost Ack then program will lock in waitting Ack.
but i watto do like When lost Ack it will return to send a new request.